# Latex how to define a simple math subtraction by new command

Tags: latex

In Latex, I want to define a simple math operation. For example, I have many numbers 1,2,3,4,5, how to subtract 1:

Like

```
\newcommand\myMath[1]%
{%
  \pgfmathparse{#1-1}%
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need `\pgfmathresult` or similar to print the result of your calculation:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\myMath[1]{%
  \pgfmathparse{#1-1}\pgfmathresult%
}


\begin{document}

\myMath{1}

\myMath{2}

\myMath{3}

\myMath{4}

\end{document}
```

If you don't want to use the heavy TikZ weapons just to do some calculations, you could use package like `xfp`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xfp}

\newcommand\myMath[1]{%
  \fpeval{#1-1}%
}


\begin{document}

\myMath{1}

\myMath{2}

\myMath{3}

\myMath{4}

\end{document}
```

Or if your calculations don't get too complicated, you could let latex do them:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\myMath[1]{%
  \number\numexpr#1-1\relax%
}


\begin{document}

\myMath{1}

\myMath{2}

\myMath{3}

\myMath{4}

\end{document}
```